# Why is an arraylist objects methods not being recognised in MainJFrame/

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, program-entry-point

I am having trouble linking an instance of an ArrayList to the mainjframe in my java program, I had initially created an arraylist object in MainjFrame called theCustomerList of type CustomerList, which holds objects of type Customer, this works as it should. I am now required to do the same thing for bank branches, so an ArrayList object called theBranchList of type BranchList has been made, and it should store objects of type Branch.

I have duplicated the code for the CustomerList class, and put it into the new BranchList class, ensuring that all key names have been switched to accommodate for the new class. Both classes have been declared and instantiated in the main j frame as shown below:

Instantiation

```
public class MainJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public MainJFrame() {
    initComponents();
theCustomer = new Customer();
theCustomerList = new CustomerList();
theBranch = new Branch();
theBranchList = new BranchList();
```

Declaration

```
private CustomerList theCustomerList;
private Customer theCustomer;
private Branch theBranch;
private BranchList theBranchList;
```

However when I call upon methods from theBranchList, it does not return any of its methods, only what looks to be the standard arraylist methods, the difference between the two results is shown below:

The `CustomerList` methods successfully displaying:

[image: CustomerList methods successfully displaying]

The `BranchList` methods not displaying:

[image: BranchList methods not displaying]

Both CustomerList class and BranchList class declare that they are arraylists of type Customer and Branch in their respective classes as shown below:

CustomerList class

```
public class CustomerList {
ArrayList<Customer>Clients;
String Filename;
Customer aCustomer;

public CustomerList(){

Clients=new ArrayList();
Filename = "CustomerAddressFile.txt";
aCustomer= new Customer();
}
```

BranchList Class

```
public class BranchList {
ArrayList<Branch>Branches;
Branch aBranch;
String Filename;


public BranchList(){
Branches = new ArrayList();
aBranch = new Branch();
Filename = "BranchAddressFile.txt";

}
```

Is anybody able to suggest what may be happening (or not happening) to cause theBranchList not to respond like an object of type Branch list when called upon? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have `class CustomerList extends ArrayList<Customer> {}` but not so parametrized for `class BranchList extends ArrayList {}`. By the way, most often no extra classes are made like CustomerList and BranchList.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the respected constructors for each class, is this what you are referring to? if not please could you explain a little more?

Comment: `List<Branch> branches; ... branches = new ArrayList<>();` with a diamond operator `<>`  so parametrized typing is done. And be carefull to on adding to always use a `new Branch()`; that `aBranch` is suspicious.

Comment: Okay this worked, thank you so much! before we finish could you please explain why CustomerList worked without having to do this? they should both be identical

Comment: There also `<>` was missing. The debugger probably saw the declarations in the other order (above the constructor or below). It is almost a bug of the debugger. I cannot explain it, hence just commented.

Comment: Okay well thanks for your reply anyway! I will speak to my tutor about it and see what she thinks. Thank you for your help :)